# Problem with Ubuntu 14.04 install

Tags: 14.04

I had the 12.04 version installed alongside with Windows 7 (using Wubi) and tried to upgrade to 14.04, but it has crashed completely. So decided to uninstall and re-install the 14.04.
Installed from the OS disk (not from a CD or a USB). The installation of Ubuntu with Unity has gone well (although, the Ubuntu Studio didn't get some permission), but at the first run I've got black screen and a message, that it couldn't find the /. directory. Tried it again, but the problem persists...
Any ideas somebody?